# "her colleague and she/her" which pronoun should I use here?

Tags: pronouns

I read a friend of mine writing this and I wondered if that was incorrect.

> her colleague and **her** were working on the web app

shouldn't this have been:

> her colleague and **she** were working on the web app

?

Comment: What is it if you remove "her colleague"?  Or if you say "XXX and her colleague were working ...."?

Answer (score 2):

Since the person working is treated as a subject, the subject case should be used. This becomes more evident if we consider that, would we  use the alternative order for the complex subject, "Her and and her colleague…"  wouldn't sound correct at all. It seems that the grammar here should not depend on such a trivial matter as word order. Is only  correct "Her colleague and she were working on the web app.", in my opinion.

Comment: A quick and easy way to remember subject/object forms is to remove the other person and see if the sentence makes sense still (while changing the verb number to match). Compare "she was working" with "her was working." The form that makes sense should be used.

Comment: @FelixJen Thanks. Yes, user Hot Licks' comment made me aware of that after I had provided my answer; however, my reasoning is not much different, if, maybe, not as systematic since the suppression appears to be a usual tool of the learners.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common in some dialects of British English to hear "her" used as the subject of a sentence. I once knocked on a door in Walsall (in the Black Country in the West Midlands of England). Eventually it was opened by a man at whose side stood a very little girl. By way of explanation for the delay he said "Her heard you, but I didn't." (His actual words were in such a strong Black Country dialect that they were incomprehensible to me, but I have rendered them in a faithful translation to preserve the main grammatical point.)

British television viewers of a certain age may recall a comedy series ("Minder") in which the leading character's (always unseen) wife was invariably described by him as "Her indoors".

If you need to ask, then you should certainly use "she" in the contexts quoted by the OP, but that usage may not always be what you hear others say.